# binding the GeometryReader in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

how to binding the GeometryReader 's item in childview? i use below code but no work?
but it show

Cannot call value of non-function type 'GeometryProxy'

is there any value to binding it?

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
geometry(geometry: geometry}

}
struct geometry: View {
    @Binding var geometry:GeometryProxy
    var body: some View {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue).opacity(0.5).blur(radius: 5)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.04, height: geometry.size.width 
              * 0.04)
}
        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this easier to understand the solution, here is a minimal reproducible example of the **problem**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            geometry(geometry: geometry)
        }
    }
}

struct geometry: View {
    @Binding var geometry: GeometryProxy

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .opacity(0.5)
            .blur(radius: 5)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.04, height: geometry.size.width * 0.04)
    }
}
```

There are 2 main issues:

1. You have two `geometry` identifiers with different meanings.
2. You cannot pass a `Binding` into the initializer.

#### #1

You have `geometry` which is a `GeometryProxy` and another `geometry` which is a `View`. The inner `geometry` (`GeometryProxy`) is preferred since it is in the most local scope. This means that you can't access the `geometry` view.

You can solve this by using a capital letter on the view, which you should do by convention anyway (to avoid problems like this):

```
struct Geometry: View {
    /* ... */
}
```

#### #2

Now that you have solved the first problem, you will now get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'GeometryProxy' to expected argument type 'Binding'

Solve this by changing the line:

```
@Binding var geometry: GeometryProxy
```

To:

```
let geometry: GeometryProxy
```

Comment: Also we can say that incoming Proxy is just read only not write! Therefore binding would gave issue, otherwise we use a custom binding for custom work